# Проблема с лямбдами

Tags: eclipse, android, java, android-sdk

Здравствуйте! Я пишу андроид-приложение и пытаюсь использовать лямбда функции. Но компилятор ругается:

```
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
```

В Интернете я читал, что надо выставить в свойствах проекта, чтобы проект компилировался совместимым с версией компилятора 1.8. Я выставил эту опцию, но вместо предыдущей ошибки получил другую:

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.8' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties
```

Когда я делаю Fix Project Properties, как это написано в сообщении об ошибке, то проект компилируется с версией компилятора 1.6, и возвращается предыдущая ошибка. Кто-нибудь знает, что здесь нужно делать, чтобы это заработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android не поддерживает Java 1.8

Comment: Не знал. Жалко. Лямбда вобще удобная вещь...

Comment: Зато есть [retrolambda][1] — "Backport of Java 8's lambda expressions to Java 7, 6 and 5". Отличная штука. Рекомендую.

  [1]: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Comment: @metalurgus толку, если не запустится на Android?

Comment: @metalurgus, дело не в используемой IDE, а в трансляторе `dex`, который не понимает байт-код Java 8.

----

> и даже JAVA 9

Ну это круто, конечно же. И вовсе не важно, что последняя версия JDK — 8u25.

Comment: @metalurgus с Retrolambda,то да.